# Does seam itself affect baking?

Tags: normals, texture-baking

[image]

Hi.
I can't bake properly. after countless time of trying I still don't know what causes this though the set up is exactly same as tutorial video. 'white' space just doesn't show up except for the little part that is below jaw which I marked seam. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html) of your mesh are facing inwards and need to be flipped. You can display your face normals, if you switch to Edit Mode, then go to your "Menu Bar - Overlay" and activate "Display face normals as lines".

[image: Display normals as lines]

Go to "Menu - Mesh - Normals - Flip Normals" to force them to face into the correct direction.

[image: Flip Normals]

Head meshes tend to have that problem sometimes. "Recalculate Outside/Inside" doesn't fix it, because the mesh has some convex/concave areas and (in many cases) isn't closed (hole in the bottom)