# Where display normals is located in Blender 2.80?

Tags: modeling, normals

I would like Blender 2.80 to display face normals in edit mode.

Where this option is located inside the GUI in Blender 2.8?

Comment: If by "draw the normals" you mean "display vertex/face normals", it's been moved to the Overlay section in the menu bar. Check out the first image in my [answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129398/does-seam-itself-affect-baking/129409#129409).

Comment: Hi @methapor_set ! Exactly! I was looking for "display vertex/face normals". Thank you!